# Python Socket Programming

Tags: python, sockets, networking, cloud

I am developing a testbed for cloud computing environment. I want to establish multiple client connection to a server. What I want is that, server first of all send a data to all the clients specifying sending_interval and then all the clients will keep on sending their data with a time gap of that time_interval (as specified by the server). Please help me out, how can I do the same using python socket program. (i.e. I want multiple client to single server connectivity and also client sending data with the time gap specified by server). Will be great-full if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's recommended that you use an existing framework such as gevent or twisted to aid you with this task. I'm not entirely sure what you need to do.

Comment: I just want that the server just sends an information (i.e. sampling time) to all the clients. Then, all the clients will keep on sending their data back to the server continuously within a time gap as specified in server's data (i.e. sampling time).

Comment: is your question "please implement this for me?" or what?

Comment: Use [`Twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/) - It makes socket programming much easier, and it tutorial will help you.

Comment: OH Plz .. I don't want you to implement this for me .. I just want to know the way we can do this .. coz I think using simple socket code .. we can't connect multiple client to single server .. anyways .. thanks Taze T. Schnitzel .. but I also want to know .. how to implement "periodic timer" in python?

Comment: @Ram Pangeni, the answer would be the same, use `Twisted`

Comment: @GaretJax .. the code I have written is in the following link : http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~rampangeni/twisted/ .... but I am facing a small problem. In the server.py code, I am taking user input from the command line. The input from the user is the sampling_interval with which client has to send its data. I am able to successfully send that value to the client side. But I am unable to use that data. Instead, the client keep on sending its data with the interval as is provided in the client.py code as LOGINTERVAL. How can I use the interval from server side instead of the LOGINTERVAL?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is **easily solved by the ZeroMQ socket library**.  It is production stable.  It allows you to define publisher-subscriber relationships, where a publishing process will publish data on a port regardless of how many (0 to infinite) listening processes there are.  They call this the PUB-SUB model; it's in their docs (link below).

It sounds like you want to set up a bunch of clients that are all publishers.  They can subscribe to a controlling channel, which which will send updates to their configuration (how often to write).  They also act as publishers, pushing out their own data at an interval specified by default/config channel/socket.

Then, you have one or more listening processes that listen to all the clients' published messages.  Perhaps you could even have two listening processes, one for backup or DR, or whatever.

**We're using ZeroMQ and loving the simplicity it gives**; there's no connection errors because the publisher doesn't care if anyone is listening, and the subscriber can start before the publisher and if there's nothing there to listen to, it can just loop around and wait until there is.

Bindings are available in ALL languages (it's freaky).  The Python binding isn't pure-python, it does require a C compiler, but is frighteningly fast, and the pub/sub example is a cut/paste, 'golly, it works!' experience.

Link:  [http://zeromq.org](http://www.zeromq.org/%20http://ZeroMQ.org)

There are MANY other methods available with this library, including message queues, etc.  They have relatively complete documentation, too.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Client and Single server Socket programming can be achieved by Multithreading in Socket Programming. I have implemented both the method:

1. Single Client and Single Server
2. Multiclient and Single Server

In my GitHub Repo Link: **https://github.com/shauryauppal/Socket-Programming-Python**

**What is Multi-threading Socket Programming?**
Multithreading is a process of executing multiple threads simultaneously in a single process.

To understand well you can visit Link: **https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/**, written by me.